# How to enable landscape orientation only for 6 and 6Plus device programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation

I am doing an iPhone project where i need to portrait and landscape support only for 6,6 Plus and iPad ? Landscape won't work for iPhone 4,5 series.

How to do it programmatically in Objective c?

Comment: just 6 and 6plus or 6, 6plus, 7 and 7 plus?

Comment: Yes.  not for 4,5 . @Vahid

Comment: i solved it already. Thanks to all for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSInteger)iPhoneType {

    struct utsname systemInfo;

    uname(&systemInfo);

    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"]) return 1;//@"iPhone 2G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"]) return 2;//@"iPhone 3G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"]) return 3;//@"iPhone 3GS";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"]) return 4;//@"iPhone 4";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"]) return 4;//@"iPhone 4";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"]) return 4;//@"iPhone 4";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"]) return 5;//@"iPhone 4S";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"]) return 5;//@"iPhone 5";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"]) return 5;//@"iPhone 5";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"]) return 6;//@"iPhone 5c";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"]) return 6;//@"iPhone 5c";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"]) return 7;//@"iPhone 5s";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"]) return 7;//@"iPhone 5s";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,4"]) return 8;//@"iPhone SE";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"]) return 9;// @"iPhone 6 Plus";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"]) return 10;//@"iPhone 6";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,1"]) return 11;//@"iPhone 6s";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,2"]) return 12;//@"iPhone 6s Plus";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,1"]) return 13;//@"iPhone 7";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,2"]) return 14;//@"iPhone 7 Plus";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])   return 15;//@"iPod Touch 1G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])   return 16;//@"iPod Touch 2G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])   return 17;//@"iPod Touch 3G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])   return 18;//@"iPod Touch 4G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])   return 19;//@"iPod Touch 5G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])   return 20;//@"iPad 1G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])   return 21;//@"iPad 2";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])   return 22;//@"iPad 2";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])   return 23;//@"iPad 2";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])   return 24;//@"iPad 2";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])   return 25;//@"iPad Mini 1G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])   return 26;//@"iPad Mini 1G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])   return 27;//@"iPad Mini 1G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])   return 28;//@"iPad 3";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])   return 29;//@"iPad 3";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])   return 30;//@"iPad 3";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])   return 31;//@"iPad 4";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])   return 32;//@"iPad 4";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])   return 33;//@"iPad 4";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])   return 34;//@"iPad Air";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])   return 35;//@"iPad Air";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,3"])   return 36;//@"iPad Air";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])   return 37;//@"iPad Mini 2G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])   return 38;//@"iPad Mini 2G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,6"])   return 39;//@"iPad Mini 2G";
    */
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])      return 40;// @"iPhone Simulator";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])    return 41;//@"iPhone Simulator";

    return 0;

}
```

You can judge by this method.

Answer (score 0):

We have `supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor` method in `UIApplicationDelegate` so you can implement it and check device height condition and return required `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` like below

**Objective-C**

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
   // iPhone 5 height:: 568 
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height > 568) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

**Swift-3**

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        // iPhone 5 height:: 568
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.height > 568 {
            return .all
        } else {
            return .portrait
        }
   }
```

Comment: Post the code in Objective C as of OP tagged Objective C not Swift

Comment: only iPhone 4/5 is portrait else its return all

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(nullable UIWindow *)window {
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) { 
         //For iPhone
         if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 568) {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
         } else {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
         }
    } else {
         //For iPad
         //your conditions for iPad 
         return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3:**

I choose this way:

> I don'e have access to Xcode to write it in Objective-C. 
>   maybe I add Objective-C code later.

First determine device model name:

```
public extension UIDevice {

var modelName: String {
    var systemInfo = utsname()
    uname(&systemInfo)
    let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
    let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
        guard let value = element.value as? Int8, value != 0 else { return identifier }
        return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
    }

    switch identifier {
    case "iPod5,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 5"
    case "iPod7,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 6"
    case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return "iPhone 4"
    case "iPhone4,1":                               return "iPhone 4s"
    case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return "iPhone 5"
    case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return "iPhone 5c"
    case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return "iPhone 5s"
    case "iPhone7,2":                               return "iPhone 6"
    case "iPhone7,1":                               return "iPhone 6 Plus"
    case "iPhone8,1":                               return "iPhone 6s"
    case "iPhone8,2":                               return "iPhone 6s Plus"
    case "iPhone9,1", "iPhone9,3":                  return "iPhone 7"
    case "iPhone9,2", "iPhone9,4":                  return "iPhone 7 Plus"
    case "iPhone8,4":                               return "iPhone SE"
    case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return "iPad 2"
    case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return "iPad 3"
    case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return "iPad 4"
    case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return "iPad Air"
    case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return "iPad Air 2"
    case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return "iPad Mini"
    case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return "iPad Mini 2"
    case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return "iPad Mini 3"
    case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return "iPad Mini 4"
    case "iPad6,3", "iPad6,4", "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":return "iPad Pro"
    case "AppleTV5,3":                              return "Apple TV"
    case "i386", "x86_64":                          return "Simulator"
    default:                                        return identifier
    }
}    
}
```

Then filter device orientation in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if  UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPhone 4"  ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPhone 5"  ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPhone 4s" ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPhone 5s" {

        return .portrait
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your device screen size is **less than or equal to iPhone 5** screen size then support only Portrait mode. Else support all type orientation for higher screen size devices. Add this code in AppDelegate.m fil

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (screenSize.height <= 568.0) {
        // If the screen size is less than or equal to iPhone 5 screen size then only Portrait mode
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    } else {
        // Else Support all the orientation. Even apple introduced new size screen devices, which is greater then iphone 5 screen size, then this will work.
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }

}
```